# objective c inserting nil object from dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, nsdictionary, nsattributedstring

I am trying to convert `HTML` into `attributedText` and store it inside of a `UITextView`. I keep getting the error

[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]

I have checked the values of the dictionaries I am using and they are not nil, I don't see what the problem is.

The attributed text is generated and has the value "Your Message Here" in red text as expected but, when I try to insert it in this line `tx.attributedText = attrString;` I get that error.

```
  UITextView *tx =[[UITextView alloc]init];
  [tx setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
  [tx setTag:1];
  tx.delegate = self;

   NSString *htmlString = @"<bold>test html</bold>";


  NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

  NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
      options:options
      documentAttributes:nil
      error:nil];

  tx.attributedText = attrString;
  return tx;
```

edit: I have simplified the code,I have removed the web request and just inserted plain html. No matter what is inserted there, I still get the same error

this is the raw value of `htmlString`: I may have messed up in pasting the value

`"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"><title></title><meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer"><style type="text/css">p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 14.0px ".SF UI Text"; color: #ff0000; background-color: #ffffff}span.s1 {font-family: ".SFUIText-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt; text-decoration: line-through}</style></head><body><p class="p1"><span class="s1">Your Message Here!</span></p</body></html>""`

`options` :

```
[0] (null)  @"DocumentType" : @"NSHTML"
```

`attrString` :

```
`attrString NSConcreteAttributedString *    @"hi test html"
```

with the `attributes    NSRLEArray *    0x7fa0fd8053a0  0x00007fa0fd8053a0`

inside of that is an `NSObject` of `isa Class   NSRLEArray  0x000000010a03ede8`

Comment: You are trying to insert nil **into** a dictionary; not from one.

Comment: Really hard to guess your problem with the supplied info, can you provide the stack when the exception occurs?

Comment: Providing the actual raw JSON may also be helpful.

Comment: Please give us the line where the execution of the app stops. There is one dictionary literal in your code, however it's unlikely that's the one that crashes.

Comment: Note that we don't alloc/init the NSError parameter usually. There is no need to.

Comment: The line of code where it stops is `tx.attributedText = attrString`

Comment: Also how can I display the stack?

Comment: Can we have the `responseString` to try to understand the issue? Could it be related to a custom font (or other attributes) that is not implemented and causes the issue? Maybe by enumerating attributes of `attrString` and find a `nil` value.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, but "[0] (null)  @"DocumentType" : @"NSHTML" " seems strange for me, why the "[0]". How did you print it? Seems to have a NSArray there (index 0, as says you error message, and with a null value too).

Comment: It was copy and paste from the inspector, the `(null)` part seems strange to me but that value is generated by objective-c from the `  NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};`

Comment: @Larme is it working for you?

Comment: I didn't got a crash when I tried to set the attrString to a `UILabel`. I didn't check the rendering though.

Comment: @Larme this isa UITextView, does it make a difference?

Comment: I tried with a UITextView, no issue. The "[0] (null)  @"DocumentType" : @"NSHTML"" still seems strange and be the one causing the issue. How did you get it? Is `options` in your code exactly the same as the one you put in the question?

Comment: yes it is exactly the same.

Comment: What is the value of attrString?

Comment: attrString could be anything I wanted it to be it would still crash right now it works correctly and is a long string of html

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the code above works fine if **it is not run on the main thread** I had to pass the textView into the function and convert the html to attributedText within it

```
    - (UITextView *)requestMessageReply:(UITextView*)textView {

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lurl"]];

  NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
  NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

  NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

  if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
    NSLog(@"Error getting HTTP status code %li", (long)[responseCode statusCode]);
     }

  NSString * responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


  //  NSString *htmlString = [self requestMessageReply];
  NSString *htmlString = (NSString *)JSON[@"message"];
  //(NSString *)JSON[@"message"]
  NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};

  NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                    options: options
                                                         documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
  textView.attributedText = attrString;
  return textView;
}
```